# How to keep logs for ECS container?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I'm running ECS tasks, and recently the service cpu hit 100% and went down.

I waited for the instance to settle down and sshed-in. 
I was looking for logs, but it seemed docker container restarted and logs are all gone (logs when the cpu was high)

Next time, how do I make sure I can see the logs at least to diagnose the problem?

I have the following, hoping to see some logs somewhere (mounted in the host machine)

```
     "mountPoints": [
            {
                "readOnly": null,
                "containerPath": "/var/log/uwsgi",
                "sourceVolume": "logs"
            }
        ],
```

But there's no `/var/log/uwsgi` in the host machine. 
And I probably need `syslog` and stuff..

Comment: Did you try `log driver`? you can push your critical logs to Cloudwatch or somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far you current configuration `logs` totally depend on the path that you define in the volume section.

```
     "mountPoints": [
            {
                "readOnly": null,
                "containerPath": "/var/log/uwsgi",
                "sourceVolume": "logs"
            }
        ],
```

the souces path defined in volume logs `logs` not `/var/log/uwsgi`, so you are mounting

`/var/log/uwsgi` (container path) -> `logs` volume (host path). you find these logs in path define in `logs` volume. but better to set something like

```
            {
                "readOnly": null,
                "containerPath": "/var/log/uwsgi",
                "sourceVolume": "volume_name"
            }
```

then volume config

```
"volumes": [
    {
      "name": "logs",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/home/ec2-user/logs"
      }
    }
]
```

From documentation

> In the task definition volumes section, define a bind mount with name
>   and sourcePath values.

```
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "webdata",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/ecs/webdata"
      }
    }
  ]
```

> In the containerDefinitions section, define a container with
>   mountPoints values that reference the name of the defined bind mount
>   and the containerPath value to mount the bind mount at on the
>   container.

```
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "image": "nginx",
      "cpu": 99,
      "memory": 100,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "webdata",
          "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

[bind-mounts-ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html)

Now if I come to my suggestion I will go for AWS log driver.

Working in AWS, the best approach is to push all logs to CW, but AWS log driver only pushes container stdout and stderr logs to CW.

Using AWS log driver you do not need to worry about instance and container, you will log in CW and you can stream these [logs to ELK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html) as well.

```
          "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-wordpress",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-example"
                }
            }
```

[image]

[using_awslogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer on multiple points. One more question though, Since awslog sends stdout/stderror, and I 'm currently logging it to file (/var/log/uwsgi and such) I 'll have to change so that services just outputs logs to stdout instead of file ?

Comment: If I may, I run multiple process nginx/uwsgi in one docker container, Is there a way to separate the logs somehow? it looks like I need to split the docker image if I want to view the logs separately (separate log group)

Comment: You can filter log based on container name but the log group will be same for this task definitions

Comment: And yes you should send logs to stdout, writing logs to file in container does not make enough sense as container suppose disposable